# How to hide but still render e.g. a partial view in MVC Razor View?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following part in a MVC Razor View:

```
@if (Model.BooleanField)
{
    @Html.Partial("PartialView")
}
```

This code does not render the code of the partial view in the DOM but I want the partial view still to be rendered in the DOM but not shown.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View:

```
<div class="@(Model.BooleanField ? null : "hidden")">
    @Html.Partial("PartialView")
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```